# How to use list comprehension with list of variable number of filenames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, list-comprehension, contextmanager

Given the list of filenames `filenames = [...]`.

Is it possibly rewrite the next list comprehension for I/O-safety: `[do_smth(open(filename, 'rb').read()) for filename in filenames]`? Using `with` statement, `.close` method or something else.

Another problem formulation: is it possibly to write I/O-safe list comprehension for the next code?

```
results = []
for filename in filenames:
   with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
      results.append(do_smth(file.read()))
```

Comment: The code you have is perfectly clear.  Don't try to put everything in a list comprehension just because you can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put the `with` statement/block to a function and call that in the list comprehension:

```
def slurp_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()

results = [do_smth(slurp_file(f)) for f in filenames]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) introduced in Python 3.3 for this purpose:

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(name, "rb")) for name in filenames]
    results = [do_smth(file.read()) for file in files]
```

Note that this opens all the files at once, which is not necessary for this use case, and might not be a good idea if you have a big number of files.